# USB port power doesn't work when PC is off

Tags: usb

Before I changed out the mothernoard in my PC, I was able to shut the PC down and plug my mp3 player in to charge. Now there's no power to the USB ports when the PC is off. Is there a setting I can change that will allow the USB ports to work when the PC is off? Thank you very much.

Comment: Motherboard make & model?

Answer (score 2):

My Lenovo Thinkpad has a BIOS setting to control whether or not it will provide power to the USB port if the laptop itself is on mains but sleeping or off.

Very useful when travelling, to use the laptop as the charging hub for 3 other devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have a formatting issue with your question you may want to edit it so its a bit easier to read.

You have a few options:

- Cheap A/C power->USB adapters are available
- Possibly putting your computer to sleep rather than fully shutting down would resolve this problem

I don't think there would be a setting for the motherboard, but if there is try entering the motherboard BIOS. This is where you can control various motherboard settings. To access it press a key on startup listed on screen, often F1, F8 or ESCAPE.

Comment: A "powered" (externally) USB hub would do fine as well.